# Duplicate bundle executions found

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

I have a parent *pom.xml* with this plug-in definition in the `pluginManagement` tag:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>default-bundle</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>bundle</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>create-source-manifest</id>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>manifest</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

And then I have the actual project's *pom.xml* that tries to add the executions:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
</plugin>
```

It results in the error: *Duplicate bundle executions found. Please remove any explicitly defined bundle executions in your pom.xml.*

However, if I remove this `plugin` tag in Eclipse and add it again, the error vanishes.

Is this an Eclipse M2E problem? Or is this an actual Maven problem? If so, how do I fix this? I can obviously not remove the executions above.

I could add this:

```
<executions>
    <execution><id>default-bundle</id></execution>
    <execution><id>create-source-manifest</id></execution>
</executions>
```

But that's very verbose for "execute everything defined in the parent pom" and if I ever want to add another execution that new one does not get executed.

**Note:** Heads up, it's still broken in Eclipse 2019-06 with M2E 1.12 (don't know which Eclipse I had over a year ago when I wrote this question).

Comment: Same problem, it seems that making ANY change (even white space) in POM and saving removes the error marker. It seems as pure eclipse bug.

Comment: It seems that this error occurs when using the Tycho Configurator. See also this issue on github. https://github.com/tesla/m2eclipse-tycho/issues/31